# Sufficient and necessary conditions for existance of a linear operator and kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the next:

Show that there exists a linear transformation $S : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$T_1 =S \circ T_2$ if and only if $\ker T_2\subset \ker T_1.$

The first implication follows because of each vector in $\ker T_2$ and $S$ is a linear operator.

To prove the other direction I have problems: I cannot see how to use the fact of the contention $\ker T_2\subset \ker T_1.$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: What is known about $T_1, T_2$? Are they linear? What is their domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $M$ be the range of $T_2$. For $y=T_2(x)$ in $M$ define $S(y)=T_1(x)$. Check that this is well defined in the sense that if we also have $y=T_2(z)$ then $T_1(x)=T_1(z)$. Now take a basis $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}$ for $M$ and extend it to a basis $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ for $\mathbb R^{n}$. Define $S ( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_ix_i)$ to be $S ( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} a_ix_i)$ (which has already been  defined).

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy.